# load img only when popup appear

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

First, I'm pretty beginner of jQuery or AJAX.

I've got around 50+ links on a web page and each link has a div#popup which contain a table and a img. It means around 50 pictures are loading when the page loads and it slower the site quite a bit.

So I would like to know if there a way to to load the picture only when mouseover the link?\

Here is the code and script I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery Popup Div on hover Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
        $('div#pop-up').show();
    }, function() {
        $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det a.ttl{
    color: #0000ff;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:12px;
    height:14px;
    display:block;
    padding:0 0 2px 0
}    

.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up table tr td img{
    border: 1px solid #e74f25;
}

.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up table{
    margin:0;
    background-color:#656565;
}

.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up table tr.firstR{
    background-color:black;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up table tr td.otherRow{
    height: 20px;
}

.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up table tr td.otherRow b{
    color: #3C3C3C;
}

/* Popup CSS */
.wpm_pag.mng_lts_chp.grp .det div#pop-up {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 110%;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="wpm_pag mng_lts_chp grp">
    <div class="det">
        <p><a href="#" class="ttl" id="trigger">this link</a></p>
    <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
    <div id="pop-up">
      <table width="650px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr class="firstR">
                <td colspan="3">Nenee! Ane Tokitoki Kanojo</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;" width="25%">Rating</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="200px" rowspan="4"><img height="200" width="200" src ="http://gooddealstore.us/icon/test.jpg" alt="xxx" /></td> /** php echo url
                <td class="otherRow" colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="otherRow"><b>Release:</b></td> /** php 
                <td class="otherRow"><b>Author:</b></td>    echo
                <td class="otherRow"><b>Artist:</b></td>   **/
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="otherRow" colspan="3"><b>Genres:</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;" colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give each anchor tag the url and make the markup like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42BV2/1/)

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="imageLink">Image 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/100x110" class="imageLink">Image 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/100x90" class="imageLink">Image 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="imageContainer">
</div>
```

js

```
var l = $(".imageLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).hover(function(e) {
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
        container = $('#imageContainer').show(),
        image = $("#imageContainer > img[src='" + imageUrl + "']");
    if(image.length > 0) {
        image.show();
    } else {
        container.append("<img src='" + imageUrl + "' />");
    }
}, function() {
    $('#imageContainer, #imageContainer > img').hide();
});
```

What I do is add an image to the dom using the `href` in the anchor.  If the element already exists (I check the images in the div using their `src`) I simply show the image.  If we apply this idea to your example, I would give the `td` element an `id` of `imageContainer` so that the image elements are added there.

Comment: Like this? <td id="imageContainer" width="200px" rowspan="4"><a href="http://gooddealstore.us/icon/test.jpg" class="imageLink"></a></td> But the img does not show up!

Comment: In my example the anchor is equal to #trigger.  I assume you will have many of those?

Comment: Yes, what i need is a script to load <img> tag inside a table when mouseover the link. For example: I have a <a href="">Text</a> when mouseover "Text" a popup will appear and the <img> tag inside the popup will load.

Comment: Well, my example is doing exactly what you want only it is using a div.  Take the idea and use it in the context of a table and td element.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this jQuery plugin : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload and YUI 2 Imageloader http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/